# SonarQube LDAP Plugin Active Directory nested groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube, nested-groups

we use Sonarqube 6.2 with the LDAP Plugin 2.1.0.507. We have a connection to our Active Diretory. Normal user authentication and group mapping is working. But we have problems with nested groups.

I try to use the specificy LDAP memberOf Filter (memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:) but unfortunally it is not working.

Questions

1. Is the LDAP Plugin able to handle nested group ?
2. If yes, what kind of changes are necessary in the filter settings ?

Attached you find my LDAP filter sonar.properties

```
  ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
  ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member=memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={dn}))
```

I hope this are enough informations.

Best Regards

Adam

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

You need only use the LDAP Reverse Code between the search pattern member={dn}

```
# Nested Group Search
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={dn}))
```

Comment: Can't upvote this enough as this really solved the issue for us as well!

Comment: This looks like a solution that works only for one specific group. Its 2023 now, is there maybe now a scalable solution that works for any number of groups so that we can automatically use nested groups for permission management.